# search concurrently pattern in a text

Tags: java, multithreading, pattern-matching

Right now I'm develop a Java program that search with threads a pattern in a text. N threads split a text in N pieces and a extra thread search "residual" cases, for example:

```
text = "AATCCCTGAATCAAATCTTA"
pattern = "AATC"
n = 2
```

then the first thread will check "AATCCCTGAA" (1..10) and the second thread will check "TCAAATCTTA" (11..20), so, the residual thread should found "AATC" (position 9 to 12). My question is, how I can make a single thread find all residual cases?

Comment: By residual, do you mean a pattern that spans from one thread to the next?

Comment: Yes, a pattern that can't be found by n threads.